# How tho fetch the json data in Javascript for the image attached,it says undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend

[image from html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPf5o.png)[this is the screenshot of the console**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu3eC.png)
2 images attached

When i am trying to fetch the id its saying Undefined. i am trying like response[0].id  . if we write like response[0] it shows json object also. 
Also if we copy the json data to console and paste the value of response to a variable and then do response[0].id then it works. but from code it doesnot.

Comment: I see that your list contains strings not the objects you expect. So `response[0]` is a string.

Comment: so.... `JSON.parse(response[0]).id` should do the trick right? - I mean once - not parsing everytime for each element of object.

Comment: Can you please post your json string and code ?

Comment: @AdamK. yes it'll work

Comment: i already attached the screenshot @user3145373

Comment: @AdamK. thank you this is working.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh just prepare the object, don't parse it everytime you want to call the objects element. (Algorithmically it would be inefficient)
`var preparedObject=JSON.parse(response[0]); preparedObject.id; preparedObject.name; preparedObject.gender;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems a problem with your JSON data.

This is the code i have written working fine with javascript.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head >
    <title>
        stack
    </title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

       <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

    </body>
    <script>
         var response=[{"id":"1", "name":"abhishek","gender":"M"},{"id":"1", "name":"abhishek","gender":"M"}];

        function myFunction() {
    console.log(response[0].id);
}
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: but my data is coming from back end. You got right, if i send employee object from javaservlet using gson then in a JSON ARRAY then this issue is happening. If i send JSon objects in JSON Array. then its working fine.

Comment: Okay, see that is a wrong JSON format. It should not be like that. It shoudl be proper JSON. I faced the same problem but I was using node.js as my backend. That problem was solved by using "bodyParser.json()" module available in node.js. So, You have to make sure correct format is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you please try something like:

```
var listdata = [{"id":"1", "name":"abhishek","gender":"M"},{"id":"2", "name":"yogesh","gender":"M"},{"id":"3", "name":"rubi","gender":"F"}];

console.dir(listdata[0].id);

alert(listdata[0].id);
```

you can see running example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/n9gy9t07/)

Comment: but my data is coming from backend as attached in the screenshot. Also from console its working.if we manullay assign it to a variable.